# XtraTreelist: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object - DragDrop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, devexpress, xtratreelist

I have an xtraTreeList with both keyFieldName and ParentFieldName are set 
in some cases while dragDrop nodes to each other i got the exception as a messageBox 
*"Operation is not valid due to the current state if the object"*
 and for that the parentField not updated!

the exception is vague, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you binding to DataTables within a DataSet? Does this only happen when you drag from a childnode *into* a parent node (that doesn't have a ParentFieldName)?

Comment: Binding to an EntitySet, it happens when drag from child to another child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please post a callstack to this error.  I am sure, that the exception is not raised by the XtraTreeList but is raised by its DataSource.  Anyway, this will give us a starting point in an attempt to find the cause of this problem.

Comment: it seems that the datasource causes this issue, thanks for the clearing up, I'm working on it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linq to sql, then make sure the parent is not loop-linked within the table, as this will require the node sorting to update the entity relation, which it does not do by itself (devex treelist)...